# Messages going missing from Apple mailboxes

Tags: email, exchange, apple-mail

A colleague has noticed random messages being deleted from her Apple Mailboxes.

e.g.  Message sent to client - client replies - original message nowhere to be found.  Not in sent items/sent messages/junk/trash.  No rules set up.

Have tried rebuilding mailboxes but message doesn't show up.  Quite worrying really as it was only noticed by chance so don't know how long/how widespread it is.

Mail is controlled by Exchange 2003 server.

Anyone come across this before or know what's happening?

Many thanks

MBP 2.53GHz
OS X 10.5.8
Mail 3.6

Comment: *Update*

Upgraded to OS to OS X 10.6 and the problem is still occurring.  Not happy.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm. This happens to me also

Snow Leopard - Exchange 2003.

I've used Entourage to get around it for now.